# How would i add 'No Data' to this php function?

Tags: php, function, ranking

I have written a PHP function to add the appropriate stems to each rank. I.E. 1st 2nd 3rd... so on and so forth.

When `$num = 0` the displayed result is `"0th"`, is there a way to display this a `'No Data'` instead?

```
function ordinalSuffix($num) {
    $suffixes = array("st", "nd", "rd");
    $lastDigit = $num % 10;

    if(($num < 20 && $num > 9) || $lastDigit == 0 || $lastDigit > 3) return "th";

    return $suffixes[$lastDigit - 1];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
function ordinalSuffix($num) {
    //Check if $num is equal to 0
    if($num == 0){
        //return
        return 'No Data';
    }
    $suffixes = array("st", "nd", "rd");
    $lastDigit = $num % 10;

    if(($num < 20 && $num > 9) || $lastDigit == 0 || $lastDigit > 3) return "th";

    return $suffixes[$lastDigit - 1];   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function ordinalSuffix($num) {
$suffixes = array("st", "nd", "rd");
$lastDigit = $num % 10;

if(($num < 20 && $num > 9) || $lastDigit == 0 || $lastDigit > 3) 
{
    return "th";
}
elseif($num == "0")
{
    return "no data";
}
return $suffixes[$lastDigit - 1];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not add to your function but I thought it would be fun to post a one-line solution anyways.

```
function ordinalSuffix($n) {
   return ($n==0?'No Data':date('S',mktime(0,0,0,1,($n%10==0?9:($n%100>20?$n%10:$n%100)),2000)));
}
```